# Select Images based on param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, carrierwave

I think this is fairly straight forward but not sure how to implement.

I have a model that is set up like so

```
create_table "portfolio_images", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "portfolio_id"
  t.string   "status"
  t.string   "image"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Within my form you can select 'Before' or 'After' for the status of each image.

If I am selecting an image within my view like so

```
<%= image_tag(i.image_url(:thumb)) %>
```

But only want to select the image with a status of 'Before', how could i select that?

if I was to create a scope

```
class PortfolioImage
  scope :portfolio_image_before, -> { where(status: 'Before') }
end
```

Would that work and how could I then use that in my view? or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

EDIT

On second thoughts I have tried this

```
<% p.portfolio_images.each do |i| %>
  <% if i.status == 'Before' %>
    <td><%= image_tag(i.image_url(:thumb)) %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But is that to hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<% p.portfolio_image.portfolio_image_before.each do |i| %>
  <%= image_tag(i.image_url(:thumb)) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, whats more efficient, the scope or the if block I have tried ?

Comment: `scope` is more efficient, suitable and standard.